# UPS Third Party Billing In Shipment API

Tags: shipping-method, ups

I am trying to send UPS Account number for third party billing but receives error that in valid shipper account, if I use same shipper account number and third party account number then shipment is success but if I add third party account number different then shipper number receiving error.
Can we send third party account number API without adding them in USP account?
The account number which I am trying is different from where I am login and using API.

Here is my code:

```
$shipment['Description'] = 'Here is description';
$shipper['Name'] = 'John Smith';
$shipper['AttentionName'] = 'John Smith';
$shipper['TaxIdentificationNumber'] = '63737YU3673';
$shipper['ShipperNumber'] = '745YUE'; //Shipper number
$address['AddressLine'] = 'Addr 1';
$address['City'] = 'City'];
$address['StateProvinceCode'] = 'State';
$address['PostalCode'] = '45635';
$address['CountryCode'] = 'DE';
$shipper['Address'] = $address;
$shipment['Shipper'] = $shipper;
    
$shipmentcharge['Type'] = '01';
$billshipper['AccountNumber'] = '4309UI'; // BILLING ACCOUNT NUMBER
$shipmentcharge['BillShipper'] = $billshipper;
$paymentinformation['ShipmentCharge'] = $shipmentcharge;
$shipment['PaymentInformation'] = $paymentinformation;

$billthirdparty['AccountNumber'] = '4309UI'; // BILLING ACCOUNT NUMBER
$billthirdparty['Address'] = 'Martin street 10';
$shipment['BillThirdParty'] = $billthirdparty;
```

Billing is not going through to third party.

Note:

4309UI account number is not added in UPS from where I am using API.

Comment: Waiting for answer from any UPS api integration expert